# get_post_permalink uses Plain even if the Post name is selected in permalink settings

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my custom function:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'get_custom_permalink', 10, 4);
function get_custom_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename = false) {
$options = get_option('my-options');
$custom_field = $options['my_field'];
//$permalink = get_option('permalink_structure');
$url = $options['agg_permalink'];
$url = str_replace("%post%", get_post_permalink($post), $url);
$url = str_replace("%site%", get_site_url(), $url);
$url = str_replace("%home%", get_home_url(), $url);
  if (!empty($url) ) {
    return $url;
    } else {
      return $permalink;
    }
}
```

`get_post_permalink($post)` is allways using Plain url the default wordpress permalink option even if Post name is selected in my permalink settings.

so the url in browser is `example.com/post_type=post&p=ID` but I want to get the post name when I use `%post%` in the field I created.

When I use `get_permalink` or `get_the_permalink` I get blank wordpress pages. Is there anything else that I can try?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Use `the_permalink()` function in loop whenever you want to use link and use `/%postname%/` instead of `%post%` in permalink setting.

Comment: Sorry I know that as you see I wrote a function and Im trying to make things from the function instead of the theme loop file. `%post%` is a custom shortcode used in plugin settings. If you check the code its using str_replace but my question is not that.